# Handle an exception thrown in a generator

Tags: python, exception, generator

I've got a generator and a function that consumes it:

```
def read():
    while something():
        yield something_else()

def process():
    for item in read():
        do stuff
```

If the generator throws an exception, I want to process that in the consumer function and then continue consuming the iterator until it's exhausted. Note that I don't want to have any exception handling code in the generator.

I thought about something like:

```
reader = read()
while True:
    try:
        item = next(reader)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except Exception as e:
        log error
        continue
    do_stuff(item)
```

but this looks rather awkward to me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is also something that I am not sure if I handle correctly/elegantly.

What I do is to `yield` an `Exception` from the generator, and then raise it somewhere else. Like:

```
class myException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, ...)
    ...

def g():
    ...
    if everything_is_ok:
        yield result
    else:
        yield myException(...)

my_gen = g()
while True:
    try:
        n = next(my_gen)
        if isinstance(n, myException):
            raise n
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except myException as e:
        # Deal with exception, log, print, continue, break etc
    else:
        # Consume n
```

This way I still carry over the Exception without raising it, which would have caused the generator function to stop. The major drawback is that I need to check the yielded result with `isinstance` at each iteration. I don't like a generator which can yield results of different types, but use it as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I ended up doing (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366892/handle-generator-exceptions-in-its-consumer))

Comment: Thanks @georg for pointing out that answer. Yielding a `tuple` with `Exception` is, I think, a better solution.

Answer (score 74):

When a generator throws an exception, it exits.  You can't continue consuming the items it generates.

Example:

```
>>> def f():
...     yield 1
...     raise Exception
...     yield 2
... 
>>> g = f()
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
Exception
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

If you control the generator code, you can handle the exception inside the generator; if not, you should try to avoid an exception occurring.

Comment: Thanks! This appears to be the case. Could you take a look at the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11366892/989121 ?

Comment: @Sven, you can't always control the exception being raised - eg from a DB SDK cursor stream (generator) which is also proprietary so the generator code is not available. Is there a workaround in such situations? (eg store stream state and  skip over the problem records?)

Comment: @alancalvitti No, once a generator throws an exception, the state is gone. There may be some non-portable hack to checkpoint it in some way, but no way you should even consider using. File a bug against that code, and look whether they have any lower-level interface you can use instead.

Answer (score 13):

I have needed to solve this problem a couple of times and came upon this question after a search for what other people have done.

---

## Throw instead of Raise

One option- which will require refactoring things a little bit- would be to `throw` the exception in the generator (to another error handling generator) rather than `raise` it. Here is what that might look like:

```
def read(handler):
    # the handler argument fixes errors/problems separately
    while something():
        try:
            yield something_else()
        except Exception as e:
            handler.throw(e)
    handler.close()

def err_handler():
    # a generator for processing errors
    while True:
        try:
            yield
        except Exception1:
            handle_exc1()
        except Exception2:
            handle_exc2()
        except Exception3:
            handle_exc3()
        except Exception:
            raise

def process():
    handler = err_handler()
    handler.send(None)  # initialize error handler
    for item in read(handler):
        do stuff
```

This isn't always going to be the best solution, but it's certainly an option.

---

## Generalized Solution

You could make it all just a bit nicer with a decorator:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass

def handled(handler):
    """
    A decorator that applies error handling to a generator.

    The handler argument received errors to be handled.

    Example usage:

    @handled(err_handler())
    def gen_function():
        yield the_things()
    """
    def handled_inner(gen_f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            g = gen_f(*args, **kwargs)
            while True:
                try:
                    g_next = next(g)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                if isinstance(g_next, Exception):
                    handler.throw(g_next)
                else:
                    yield g_next
        return wrapper
    handler.send(None)  # initialize handler
    return handled_inner

def my_err_handler():
    while True:
        try:
            yield
        except MyError:
            print("error  handled")
        # all other errors will bubble up here

@handled(my_err_handler())
def read():
    i = 0
    while i<10:
        try:
            yield i
            i += 1
            if i == 3:
                raise MyError()
        except Exception as e:
            # prevent the generator from closing after an Exception
            yield e

def process():
    for item in read():
        print(item)


if __name__=="__main__":
    process()
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
error  handled
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

However the downside of this is you have still have to put generic `Exception` handling inside the generator that might produce errors. It isn't possible to get around this, since raising any exception in a generator will close it.

---

## Kernel of an Idea

It would be nice to have some kind `yield raise` statement, which allows the generator to continue running if it can after the error was raised. Then you could write code like this:

```
@handled(my_err_handler())
def read():
    i = 0
    while i<10:
        yield i
        i += 1
        if i == 3:
            yield raise MyError()
```

...and the `handler()` decorator could look like this:

```
def handled(handler):
    def handled_inner(gen_f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            g = gen_f(*args, **kwargs)
            while True:
                try:
                    g_next = next(g)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    handler.throw(e)
                else:
                    yield g_next
        return wrapper
    handler.send(None)  # initialize handler
    return handled_inner
```

Comment: Your decorator approach cannot work. The generator exits after the exception is raised. Otherwise the idea with an error handling generator is nice.

Comment: @C.Yduqoli Yeah I haven't looked at this one in a while but you're probably right about the decorator.

Answer (score 4):

After Python 3.3 a code for catching exception from the original generator will be very symple:

```py
from types import GeneratorType


def gen_decorator(func):
    def gen_wrapper(generator):
        try:
            yield from generator  # I mean this line!
        except Exception:
            print('catched in gen_decorator while iterating!'.upper())
            raise

    def wrapper():
        try:
            result = func()

            if isinstance(result, GeneratorType):
                result = gen_wrapper(result)

            return result
        except Exception:
            print('catched in gen_decorator while initialization!'.upper())
            raise

    return wrapper
```

And example of usage:

```py
@gen_decorator
def gen():
    x = 0
    while True:
        x += 1

        if x == 5:
            raise RuntimeError('error!')

        yield x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        for i in gen():
            print(i)

            if i >= 10:
                print('lets stop!')
                break
    except Exception:
        print('catched in main!'.upper())
        raise
```