# Handle generator exceptions in its consumer

Tags: python, exception, generator

This is a follow-up to [Handle an exception thrown in a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11366064/989121) and discusses a more general problem.

I have a function that reads data in different formats. All formats are line- or record-oriented and for each format there's a dedicated parsing function, implemented as a generator. So the main reading function gets an input and a generator, which reads its respective format from the input and delivers records back to the main function:

```
def read(stream, parsefunc):
    for record in parsefunc(stream):
        do_stuff(record)
```

where `parsefunc` is something like:

```
def parsefunc(stream):
    while not eof(stream):
        rec = read_record(stream)
        do some stuff
        yield rec
```

The problem I'm facing is that while `parsefunc` can throw an exception (e.g. when reading from a stream), it has no idea how to handle it. The function responsible for handling exceptions is the main `read` function. Note that exceptions occur on a per-record basis, so even if one record fails, the generator should continue its work and yield records back until the whole stream is exhausted.

In the previous question I tried to put `next(parsefunc)` in a `try` block, but as turned out, this is not going to work. So I have to add `try-except` to the `parsefunc` itself and then somehow deliver exceptions to the consumer:

```
def parsefunc(stream):
    while not eof(stream):
        try:
            rec = read_record()
            yield rec
        except Exception as e:
            ?????
```

I'm rather reluctant to do this because

- it makes no sense to use `try` in a function that isn't intended to handle any exceptions
- it's unclear to me how to pass exceptions to the consuming function
- there going to be many formats and many `parsefunc`'s, I don't want to clutter them with too much helper code.

Has anyone suggestions for a better architecture?

Comment: Discussing a design usually requires quite detailed knowledge of the system, so it seems hard to give advice here.  My first idea would be to do away with `parsefunc()`, and pass `read_record` to `read()`.  This way, the exceptions could be handled right after the call to `read_record()`.

Comment: I agree with @SvenMarnach - the way I'm reading it though is this is potentially over-complicated - ie., `parsefunc()` is responsible for consuming a record, but then - how is an appropriate `parsefunc()` chosen for the rest of the stream?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: actually, what I described as `do some stuff` in `parsefunc` is a fairly big chunk of code, so I can't simply get rid of it.

Comment: @JonClements: whoever calls `read` knows in which format the data comes in, and decides which parser to use.

Comment: @where is `eof` defined?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can return a tuple of record and exception in the parsefunc and let the consumer function decide what to do with the exception:

```
import random

def get_record(line):
  num = random.randint(0, 3)
  if num == 3:
    raise Exception("3 means danger")
  return line


def parsefunc(stream):
  for line in stream:
    try:
      rec = get_record(line)
    except Exception as e:
      yield (None, e)
    else:
      yield (rec, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with open('temp.txt') as f:
    for rec, e in parsefunc(f):
      if e:
        print "Got an exception %s" % e
      else:
        print "Got a record %s" % rec
```

Answer (score 14):

Thinking deeper about what would happen in a more complex case kind of vindicates the Python choice of avoiding bubbling exceptions out of a generator.

If I got an I/O error from a stream object the odds of simply being able to recover and continue reading, without the structures local to the generator being reset in some way, would be low.  I would somehow have to reconcile myself with the reading process in order to continue: skip garbage, push back partial data, reset some incomplete internal tracking structure, etc.

Only the generator has enough context to do that properly.  Even if you could keep the generator context, having the outer block handle the exceptions would totally flout the Law of Demeter.  All the important information that the surrounding block needs to reset and move on is in local variables of the generator function!  And getting or passing that information, though possible, is disgusting.

The resulting exception would almost always be thrown *after* cleaning up, in which case the reader-generator will already have an internal exception block.  Trying very hard to maintain this cleanliness in the brain-dead-simple case only to have it break down in almost every realistic context would be silly. So just *have* the `try` in the generator, you are going to need the body of the `except` block anyway, in any complex case.

It would be nice if exceptional conditions could look like exceptions, though, and not like return values.  So I would add an intermediate adapter to allow for this:  The generator would yield either data or exceptions and the adapter would re-raise the exception if applicable.  The adapter should be called first-thing inside the for loop, so that we have the option of catching it within the loop and cleaning up to continue, or breaking out of the loop to catch it and and abandon the process.  And we should put some kind of lame wrapper around the setup to indicate that tricks are afoot, and to force the adapter to get called if the function is adapting.

That way each layer is presented errors that it has the context to handle, at the expense of the adapter being a tiny bit intrusive (and perhaps also easy to forget).

So we would have:

```
def read(stream, parsefunc):
  try:
    for source in frozen(parsefunc(stream)):
      try:
        record = source.thaw()
        do_stuff(record)
      except Exception, e:
        log_error(e)
        if not is_recoverable(e):
          raise
        recover()
  except Exception, e:
    properly_give_up()
  wrap_up()
```

(Where the two `try` blocks are optional.)

The adapter looks like:

```
class Frozen(object):
  def __init__(self, item):
    self.value = item
  def thaw(self):
    if isinstance(value, Exception):
      raise value
    return value

def frozen(generator):
    for item in generator:
       yield Frozen(item)
```

And `parsefunc` looks like:

```
def parsefunc(stream):
  while not eof(stream):
    try:
       rec = read_record(stream)
       do_some_stuff()
       yield rec
    except Exception, e:
       properly_skip_record_or_prepare_retry()
       yield e
```

To make it harder to forget the adapter, we could also change frozen from a function to a decorator on parsefunc.

```
def frozen_results(func):
  def freezer(__func = func, *args, **kw):
    for item in __func(*args, **kw):
       yield Frozen(item)
  return freezer
```

In which case we we would declare:

```
@frozen_results
def parsefunc(stream):
  ...
```

And we would obviously not bother to declare `frozen`, or wrap it around the call to `parsefunc`.

Answer (score 7):

One option would be to use a *callback*. Given that only `read` knows how to deal with exceptions, might something like this work?

```
def read(stream, parsefunc):
    some_closure_data = {}

    def error_callback_1(e):
        manipulate(some_closure_data, e)
    def error_callback_2(e):
        transform(some_closure_data, e)

    for record in parsefunc(stream, error_callback_1):
        do_stuff(record)
```

Then, in `parsefunc`:

```
def parsefunc(stream, error_callback):
    while not eof(stream):
        try:
            rec = read_record()
            yield rec
        except Exception as e:
            error_callback(e)
```

I used a closure over a mutable local here; you could also define a class. Note also that you can access the `traceback` info via `sys.exc_info()` inside the callback.

Another interesting approach *might* be to use `send`. This would work a little differently; basically, instead of defining a callback, `read` could check the result of `yield`, do a lot of complex logic, and `send` a substitute value, which the generator would then re-yield (or do something else with). This is a bit more exotic, but I thought I'd mention it in case it's useful:

```
>>> def parsefunc(it):
...     default = None
...     for x in it:
...         try:
...             rec = float(x)
...         except ValueError as e:
...             default = yield e
...             yield default
...         else:
...             yield rec
... 
>>> parsed_values = parsefunc(['4', '6', '5', '5h', '22', '7'])
>>> for x in parsed_values:
...     if isinstance(x, ValueError):
...         x = parsed_values.send(0.0)
...     print x
... 
4.0
6.0
5.0
0.0
22.0
7.0
```

On it's own this is a bit useless ("Why not just print the default directly from `read`?" you might ask), but you could do more complex things with `default` inside the generator, resetting values, going back a step, and so on. You could even wait to send a callback at *this* point based on the error you receive. But note that `sys.exc_info()` is cleared as soon as the generator `yield`s, so you'll have to send everything from `sys.exc_info()` if you need access to the traceback.

Here's an example of how you might combine the two options:

```
import string
digits = set(string.digits)

def digits_only(v):
    return ''.join(c for c in v if c in digits)

def parsefunc(it):
    default = None
    for x in it:
        try:
            rec = float(x)
        except ValueError as e:
            callback = yield e
            yield float(callback(x))
        else:
            yield rec

parsed_values = parsefunc(['4', '6', '5', '5h', '22', '7'])
for x in parsed_values:
    if isinstance(x, ValueError):
        x = parsed_values.send(digits_only)
    print x
```

Answer (score 3):

An example of a possible design:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import csv

blah = StringIO('this,is,1\nthis,is\n')

def parse_csv(stream):
    for row in csv.reader(stream):
        try:
            yield int(row[2])
        except (IndexError, ValueError) as e:
            pass # don't yield but might need something
        # All others have to go up a level - so it wasn't parsable
        # So if it's an IOError you know why, but this needs to catch
        # exceptions potentially, just let the major ones propogate

for record in parse_csv(blah):
    print record
```

Answer (score 2):

About your point of propagating exception from generator to consuming function, 
you can try to use an error code (set of error codes) to indicate the error.
Though not elegant that is one approach you can think of.

For example in the below code yielding a value like -1 where you were expecting 
a set of positive integers would signal to the calling function that there was
an error.

```
In [1]: def f():
  ...:     yield 1
  ...:     try:
  ...:         2/0
  ...:     except ZeroDivisionError,e:
  ...:         yield -1
  ...:     yield 3
  ...:     


In [2]: g = f()

In [3]: next(g)
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: next(g)
Out[4]: -1

In [5]: next(g)
Out[5]: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the given answer with the `Frozen` stuff.  Based on that idea I came up with this, solving two aspects I did not yet like.  The first was the patterns needed to write it down.  The second was the loss of the stack trace when yielding an exception.  I tried my best to solve the first by using decorators as good as possible.  I tried keeping the stack trace by using `sys.exc_info()` instead of the exception alone.

My generator normally (i.e. without my stuff applied) would look like this:

```
def generator():
  def f(i):
    return float(i) / (3 - i)
  for i in range(5):
    yield f(i)
```

If I can transform it into using an inner function to determine the value to yield, I can apply my method:

```
def generator():
  def f(i):
    return float(i) / (3 - i)
  for i in range(5):
    def generate():
      return f(i)
    yield generate()
```

This doesn't yet change anything and calling it like this would raise an error with a proper stack trace:

```
for e in generator():
  print e
```

Now, applying my decorators, the code would look like this:

```
@excepterGenerator
def generator():
  def f(i):
    return float(i) / (3 - i)
  for i in range(5):
    @excepterBlock
    def generate():
      return f(i)
    yield generate()
```

Not much change optically.  And you still can use it the way you used the version before:

```
for e in generator():
  print e
```

And you still get a proper stack trace when calling.  (Just one more frame is in there now.)

But now you also can use it like this:

```
it = generator()
while it:
  try:
    for e in it:
      print e
  except Exception as problem:
    print 'exc', problem
```

This way you can handle in the consumer any exception raised in the generator without too much syntactic hassle and without losing stack traces.

The decorators are spelled out like this:

```
import sys

def excepterBlock(code):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
      return (code(*args, **kwargs), None)
    except Exception:
      return (None, sys.exc_info())
  return wrapper

class Excepter(object):
  def __init__(self, generator):
    self.generator = generator
    self.running = True
  def next(self):
    try:
      v, e = self.generator.next()
    except StopIteration:
      self.running = False
      raise
    if e:
      raise e[0], e[1], e[2]
    else:
      return v
  def __iter__(self):
    return self
  def __nonzero__(self):
    return self.running

def excepterGenerator(generator):
  return lambda *args, **kwargs: Excepter(generator(*args, **kwargs))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option- which will probably require refactoring things a little bit- would be to simply create an error handling generator, and `throw` the exception in the generator (to another error handling generator) rather than `raise` it.

Here is what the error handling generator function might look like:

```
def err_handler():
    # a generator for processing errors
    while True:
        try:
            # errors are thrown to this point in function
            yield
        except Exception1:
            handle_exc1()
        except Exception2:
            handle_exc2()
        except Exception3:
            handle_exc3()
        except Exception:
            raise
```

An additional `handler` argument is provided to the `parsefunc` function so it has a place to put the errors:

```
def parsefunc(stream, handler):
    # the handler argument fixes errors/problems separately
    while not eof(stream):
        try:
            rec = read_record(stream)
            do some stuff
            yield rec
        except Exception as e:
            handler.throw(e)
    handler.close()
```

Now just use almost the original `read` function, but now with an error handler:

```
def read(stream, parsefunc):
    handler = err_handler()
    for record in parsefunc(stream, handler):
        do_stuff(record)
```

This isn't always going to be the best solution, but it's certainly an option, and relatively easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, generators are quite limited in several aspects.  You found one: the raising of exceptions is not part of their API.

You could have a look at the Stackless Python stuff like greenlets or coroutines which offer a lot more flexibility; but diving into that is a bit out of scope here.