# Can I route Luigi pipeline errors to Sentry?

Tags: python, sentry, luigi

My team uses `Sentry` to track errors, and so I would prefer to not use Luigi's built-in email capabilities to keep all our reporting in one place.

This is how I have it currently set up, and it seems to be skipping Sentry entirely:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        luigi.run()
    except Exception as e:
        client = Client(
            ***
        )
        client.captureException(tags={
            sys.argv[0]
        })
        logger.critical('Error occurred: {e}'.format(e=e))
        raise
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be possible if you declare a [callback to the failure event](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html?highlight=failure#events-and-callbacks) and do the sentry tracking stuff there:

```
import luigi

@luigi.Task.event_handler(luigi.Event.FAILURE)
def mourn_failure(task, exception):
    client = Client(
        ***
    )
    # we also include extra context for the current task
    client.captureException(
       (type(e), e.message, e.traceback),
       extra=dict(task=repr(task))
    )
    logger.critical('Error occurred: {e}'.format(e=exception))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

**NOTICE** that `e.traceback` will only work on python 3+ [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14564261/3219121).