# Retrieve stack trace in django Middleware

Tags: django

How can I get the stack trace when something fails on the server side in the django middleware?
Here is what I've tried that only gives me the message, not the full stack.

```
class MonitorMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        self.error = exception.message
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414894/extract-traceback-info-from-an-exception-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to "retrieve the error stack trace to save to the database" from comment:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Use the methods of `traceback` to convert the trace of the exception into a string which you can then store in the database.

Also on the above page:

> New in version 3.5.
>
> StackSummary objects represent a call stack ready for formatting.

The short short example with an exception object:

```
>>> an_error = IndexError('tuple index out of range')
>>> traceback.print_exception(type(an_error), an_error, an_error.__traceback__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

See also [Extract traceback info from an exception object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414894/extract-traceback-info-from-an-exception-object):
You don't need to re-raise the exception, though, the traceback is in the `__traceback__` attribute.

Comment: Hi. I'm not trying to insert information into the logs; I'm trying to retrieve the error stack trace to save to the database for example something goes wrong in a view or controller and the middleware records it in the database .

Comment: uh, I don't know why I thought it does not work...I used traceback.format_exc()