# get_row function ignored in python

Tags: python, function, csv, printing

I wrote a function to get row data from a csv file,which failed .so I insert so many "print"s to see  what is wrong.but to my surprise,the console just keeps empty,that's quit strange.I have reindent my code for so many times
my code is blew:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

def get_rows(csv_file):
    print '0'
    reader=csv.reader(open(csv_file))
    print '1'
    #get the colnum names,lowercased
    col_names=tuple(k.lower() for k in reader.next())
    print '2' 
    for row in reader:
        yield dict(zip(col_names,row))
    print col_names

def main():
    file_name='companylist.csv'

    try:
        get_rows(file_name)
    except:
        print 'OK'
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

---

while code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open('companylist.csv'))
col_names=tuple(k.lower() for k in reader.next())
for row in reader:
    dict(zip(col_names,row))
print col_names
```

work s perfectly,resulted in:

```
('symbol', 'name', 'lastsale', 'marketcap', 'adr tso', 'ipoyear', 'sector', 'industry', 'summary quote', '')
```

while code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

def main():
    reader=csv.reader(open('companylist.csv'))
    col_names=tuple(k.lower() for k in reader.next())
    print '1'
    print col_names
    for row in reader:
        yield dict(zip(col_names,row))
    print col_names

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

### resulted in nothing

and code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
def get_rows(csv_file):
    print '0'
    reader=csv.reader(open(csv_file))
    print '1'
    #get the colnum names,lowercased
    col_names=tuple(k.lower() for k in reader.next())
    print '2' 
    for row in reader:
        yield dict(zip(col_names,row))
    print col_names
def main():
    file_name='companylist.csv'

    try:
        if(get_rows(file_name)):
            print "OK"
    except Exception,ex:
        print Exception,":",ex
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

resulted in :`OK`

Comment: You're not even getting the `"OK"` from an exception? Also, don't catch naked exceptions like that. You're losing all the valuable information that different exceptions might contain.

Comment: Are you importing this to another module?

Comment: if none of those prints are running, it probably means that python is not reading an indentation error, but you have one. Maybe 4 spaces instead of an indent. This recently happened to me and caused one of my while loops to end before reassigning the value so it went on forever. I just needed to re-indent that line and everything worked out

Comment: I re-indent all the lines,but still got even no "OK"

Comment: does it work if you do it from just a regular statement rather than another function: `get_rows('companylist.csv')`

Comment: code :# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open('companylist.csv'))
col_names=tuple(k.lower() for k in reader.next())
for row in reader:
    dict(zip(col_names,row))
print col_names
 works perfectly resulted in:('symbol', 'name', 'lastsale', 'marketcap', 'adr tso', 'ipoyear', 'sector', 'industry', 'summary quote', '')

Answer (score 2):

As your `get_rows` is a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions), it executes only when one of the generator methods is called (e.g., `for...in` expression internally calls `next()` method for an iterable object). So rewriting your `main` function should help:

```
def main():
    file_name='companylist.csv'

    try:
        for row in get_rows(file_name):
            print row
    except:
        print 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

You define a generator function `get_rows`, which only yields a value when you call it as an iterator. So, unless you insert `print` statements in your `main` function, you just print the generator function in the row `get_rows(file_name)` (which is fine, raising no exception), which does not execute it! Therefore, none of the many `print` statements are executed.

Try looping over `get_rows(file_name)` and see what happens, i.e. like this

```
for element in get_rows(file_name):
    # do something with element
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that 'yield' stops the function from behaving as a function.  If you change it to return, you will see your exception (my python 3 says that reader has no next() function) and your prints.

I have not found any documentation (yet) on how generators suppress print statements, but that does seem to be the case with simple code such as:

```
def mygen():
    print('1')
    yield 1
```

Regarding the exception, take a look at this:

[Handle generator exceptions in its consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366892/handle-generator-exceptions-in-its-consumer)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has pointed out already, you are using a generator, which is why it doesn't execute until you call the generator's `.next` or `.__next__` (on Python 3) for the first time. However I'm going to suggest a better way of making your `get_rows` function with lowercase column names:

```
import csv

def get_rows(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file) as f:
        return csv.DictReader(f, next(f).lowercase().split(','))
```