# How to rollback transactions in a loop django

Tags: python, django, database, transactions

I'm trying to rollback a group of transactions if there are exceptions thrown in the loop. But I don't want to break out of the loop or throw an exception without catching it.

I don't want the business logic to be saved if any of the children in the loop throw an exception. So that means I can't put the transaction inside the loop because if any of them fails it would only rollback the transaction for the specific child.

```
parent = Parent.objects.get(pk='something')
exceptions = []
with transaction.atomic():
    for child in parent.children.all():
        try:
            # business logic which also saves other models
            # I don't want this saved if there is an exception for any object in the loop
        except Exception as e:
            exceptions.append({
                'id': child.id,
                'error': str(e),
            })
if len(exceptions) > 0:
    transaction.set_rollback(True)
    for exception in exceptions:
        Child.objects.filter(pk=exception['id']) \
            .update(error=exception['error']
    # more business logic and raise exception
    parent.is_blocked = True
    parent.save()
    # I don't want this exception to rollback all transactions
    raise Exception('Parent {} is blocked'.format(parent.id))
```

I'm getting an error with the above code. The message is pretty straight forward. I'm trying to rollback the transaction outside of the block.

`django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: The rollback flag doesn't work outside of an 'atomic' block.`

Has anyone found a way to handle something like this. I hope I'm just missing something simple. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

[`Avoid catching exceptions inside atomic!`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly)

Follow the document, and with your special case, your code should be like this:

```
parent = Parent.objects.get(pk='something')
exceptions = []
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        for child in parent.children.all():
            try:
                # business logic which also saves other models
                # I don't want this saved if there is an exception for any object in the loop
            except Exception as e:
                exceptions.append({
                    'id': child.id,
                    'error': str(e),
                })
        # raise exception handly to trigger rollback
        if len(exceptions) > 0:
            raise("raise for rollback")
except Exception as e:
    pass

if len(exceptions) > 0:
    for exception in exceptions:
        Child.objects.filter(pk=exception['id']) \
            .update(error=exception['error']
    # more business logic and raise exception
    parent.is_blocked = True
    parent.save()
    # I don't want this exception to rollback all transactions
    raise Exception('Parent {} is blocked'.format(parent.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a generator function:

```
def function():
    for child in parent.children.all():
        try:
            yield result
        except Exception as e:
            yield exception
```

You can check out this answer for clarity:
[How to handle error thrown in a generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366064/handle-an-exception-thrown-in-a-generator)

Comment: Would you mind giving some more explanation? How does this solve the problem of rolling back the transaction if there were any exceptions thrown?

Comment: The generator function basically returns the exception when an error occurs, so if you check the link i showed you (it is an answered question) will see a better explanation of how to implement it

Comment: I appreciate the idea. I don't think this solves the problem. I could be missing something but I'm already catching the exception and adding it to an array.