# How to ignore exceptions occuring within a call to rglob?

Tags: python, pathlib

I am using `pathlib.Path.rglob` to browse through some files in a directory hierarchy. However one of the (sub-sub-...) directory cannot be parsed and an exception is thrown.

```
import pathlib
for file in pathlib.Path(r'\\path\to\shared\folder').rglob('*.foo'):
  pass
# OSError: [WinError 59] An unexpected network error occurred
```

Catching the exception in the body of the `for` loop makes no sense as the exeption occurs in `rglob`. Putting the entire loop within a `try` block does catch the exception, but then I cannot resume the computation.

Does anybody have a clue about how to do that with `pathlib.Path.rglob`? A work around is to use good old `os.walk` but I would be interested in knowing a solution for this supposedly more modern tool.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, try to run `filePaths = Path(r'\\path\to\shared\folder').rglob('*.foo')` in your python shell to see whether it completes without an error. If so, you can try to catch runtime-exceptions (probably due to unstable network connection) during the iteration.

```
def try_loop(g):
    while True:
        try:
            yield next(g)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except OSError as e:
            # log error
            continue
```

Then wrap your `rglob` call in the `try_loop` function

```
for file in try_loop(pathlib.Path(r'\\path\to\shared\folder').rglob('*.foo')):
    pass
```

This is inspired by a more general question ["Handle an exception thrown in a generator"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11366064/6238076).

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you linked states that generators exit after they throw an exception. So what's the point of your `try_loop` function?

Comment: @Aran-Fey indeed the generator does not go past the faulty folder, so this is equivalent to the outer `try/except` block (even though it catches the exception of the generator only, not of the entire loop body).

Comment: The `try_loop` function doesn't guarantee that you can continue the loop after an exception. It only suppress the error so that you don't need to use a try block to enclose the entire loop. The implementation of `rglob` makes it impossible to recover from an error. Internally it handles only [permission error](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9a0000d15d27361eaa47b77600c7c00a9787a894/Lib/pathlib.py#L528).