# Fetching data from Redshift fails with no workaround - UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decode bytes

Tags: encoding, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am fetching data from Amazon Redshift.
More precisely, I am querying table `stl_query_text` to extract the list of queries which ran on a specific day.

Here's the Python script fetching data, using **SqlAlchemy**.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

_QUERY = """
SELECT 
    q.query AS query_id,
    qt.text
FROM 
    pg_catalog.stl_query AS q
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.stl_querytext AS qt
    ON q.query = qt.query
WHERE TRUE
    AND DATE(q.starttime) = '2023-10-24'
    AND EXTRACT('hour' FROM q.starttime) = 19
"""

uri = "postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}".format(**_secrets)
engine = create_engine(uri)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    
   result = connection.execute(_QUERY)
    
   for row in result:
        print(row)
```

It was working well until recently. It fails with the following error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 656: invalid continuation byte`

Apparently, some queries have a weird character sequence in their text. If I run the same query without `qt.text`, it works fine. But I need the text.

I tried many things but I could not find any workaround:

### 1st attempt - fix the decoding error

Would be the best option if it worked. I have tried specifying the charset in the URI as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972363/sqlalchemy-and-unicodedecodeerror)

- `client_encoding=utf8` => I get the same error since it's the default encoding
- `client_encoding=latin1` => FATAL:  invalid value for parameter "client_encoding": "latin1"

  - any other encoding such as `ISO-8859-1` are not accepted

### 2nd attempt - skip the faulty rows

It would be a partial fetch but I'm fine with it. I don't really need the faulty rows.
However, I could not make it work.

using `try ... except` or `throw instead of rise` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366064/handle-an-exception-thrown-in-a-generator)

It works partially: I can fetch all rows until the cursor meets the faulty row. After that, the generator stops as mentioned in the thread:

> However the downside of this is you have still have to put generic Exception handling inside the generator that might produce errors. It isn't possible to get around this, since raising any exception in a generator will close it.

The problem is that the generator is inside **SqlAlchemy**, I cannot modify it.

I also tried to ignore encoding errors as mentioned [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4932#issuecomment-545034484)

> engine = create_engine(uri, encoding_errors='ignore')

But apparently this parameter is not accepted:

> TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'encoding_errors' sent to create_engine(), using configuration PGDialect_psycopg2/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.

### 3rd attempt - exclude the faulty rows using WHERE

I tried to adapt my query to exclude the faulty rows.

For example:

```sql
SELECT 
    q.query AS query_id,
    qt.text
FROM 
    pg_catalog.stl_query AS q
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.stl_querytext AS qt
    ON q.query = qt.query
WHERE TRUE
    AND DATE(q.starttime) = '2023-10-24'
    AND EXTRACT('hour' FROM q.starttime) = 19
    AND qt.text NOT LIKE '%0xc2%'
```

It did not work, but it's not surprising since I am searching for a byte sequence in a VARCHAR.

### 4th attempt - use another library

I tried to replace **SqlAlchemy** with [redshift-connector](https://pypi.org/project/redshift-connector/) but I get the same decoding error.

Any idea would be much appreciated! Thanks a lot

Comment: Try installing [sqlalchemy-redshift](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-redshift/) and using `redshift+psycopg2://…`

Comment: Thanks for your help! 

- I get the same error when using `sqlalchemy-redshift`. It's more appropriate anyway, so I will keep this.

- The approach suggested by chatGPT did not work either. The reason is that SqlAlchemy already converts bytes to string, I don't have the control on this.

Comment: What are the client and server encodings?

Comment: You are correct to assert that decoding takes place automatically before application code can do anything with the data. So it would be helpful to have an example of the data (doesn't have to be a complete query, just enough to reproduce, and some idea of how it is getting into the database.  At a guess,  there could be some combination of database and client session encodings involved (I already asked for this information), but as it is it's hard to know how to solve the problem without knowing how that data was generated.

Comment: Have you tried to 'catch the error' in sql instead of your code? For example, create a UDF like suggested in this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28412587/1800344.

Comment: Have you tried with explicit cast to varchar?
`SELECT 
    ...
    qt.text::varchar`